# Shape tween in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

Is there a way to do a shape tween in javascript? 
Using canvas maybe...

Comment: like flash... I have a square and transform into a circle for example...

Comment: http://www.entheosweb.com/Flash/shape_tween.asp

Comment: A demo of shape tweening in JavaScript can be found here: http://jembezmamy.github.com/morpher-js/demos.html

Comment: Also, here's a JavaScript library for shape tweening: https://github.com/jembezmamy/morpher-js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you will be doing graphics on the HTML 5 canvas element, you may want to check the [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) library. There is a [tweening library](http://quasipartikel.at/tween/), but you will probably find it helpful [for many other things](http://processingjs.org/exhibition).

> Processing.js uses JavaScript to draw
>   shapes and manipulate images on the
>   HTML 5 Canvas element. The code is
>   light-weight, simple to learn and
>   makes an ideal tool for visualizing
>   data, creating user-interfaces and
>   developing web-based games.

For tweening, you may want to have a look at the following:

- [Tween.lib - Motion Tweening for Processing.js](http://quasipartikel.at/tween/)
- [Motion Tweening for Processing.js](http://quasipartikel.at/2009/11/30/motion-tweening-for-processingjs/)

Comment: Is it possible to use any of these libraries to morph one shape into another shape (which is what the question appears to be asking), or do they only do motion tweening?

Answer (score 7):

Shape tween as in Flash is harder to find than motion tween and simple attributes interpolation (like in JSTweener, Tween.lib, JQuery's animate(), d3's transition(), RaphaelJS's animate(), etc.). Those libraries, some cited in the other answers, don't do shape tweening.

You first need to know if you want to draw with SVG or with canvas and what library you will be using. Then, you need an interpolator, a function that will compute the transition between two given shapes, that can write a proper path in SVG or canvas. I wrote an implementation for SVG in D3.js to do some animated transitions between a lot of different shapes (using Gielis's [superformula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superformula)), if someone still need one. You can find an example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/1020902)

Comment: Great answer and demo!  I like the simple solution of tweening the radial distance of points on a circle.

Comment: That demo is awesome! Exactly what I am searching for! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Some animated examples here combine motion|shape tweening using RaphaelJS.  Check out the ones on the bottom:
http://raphaeljs.com/animation.html

Answer (score 1):

For tweens in Javascript use http://coderepos.org/share/wiki/JSTweener

Comment: Didn't exactly answer the primary question (as it doesn't do shape tweens), but it certainly helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I use tween.js (http://learningthreejs.com/) a great library that will tween anything.  If you already use jQuery I would also recommend looking into it's animate function.