# Diffing 2 SVGs, or find the minimal modifications to transition from one to the other

Tags: svg

I want to diff 2 SVGs to find the minimal steps to transition from one to the other.

That is (as far as I understand) basically the same, what all those vDOM implementation do for diffing the DOM.

But I need it:

- to run in nodejs
- to use it with svg

So here my questions:

- Is there a diffing library for SVGs that I have missed, that does this?
- Is there a documented algorithm for doing DOM/SVG diffing? I could implement it myself, I have to admit I struggle coming up with a good algorithm for it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576746/algorithm-to-morph-one-shape-into-another

Comment: @TamásSengel Thank you for the tip! This is what I want to do after I found the diff :)

Comment: [hiff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hiff) (forked as [html-compare](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-compare)) is based on cheerio, which works really fine with SVG if you load files in XML mode. I am unsure whether hiff allows this sort of config.

Comment: @Nathan: please expand on how the compared data should look like: e.g. an array of coordinate delta values? Obviously you need to diff svg elements like `path` or maybe just `polygon`s  based on absolute coordinates.  Either way, a sheer markup based diff method will most likely not provide usable data. It's also important, if your svg elements are comparable/compatible at all – if element 1 ist based on absolute and cubic bezier commands but element 2 on quadratic and relative commands ... you will need some normalizing first.