# How do I animate this SVG clip-path hover effect?

Tags: css, animation, svg

I am trying to animate the transformation a clip-path from a triangle to a square on the hover state, but I just can't seem to get it working right.

I set up a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/jcypykdk/ which essentially shows what I want to do, minus any animation.

HTML:

```
<svg id="svg-1" class="clip-svg" width="150" height="150">
    <a xlink:href="http://google.com" class="svg-link">
        <image id="img-1" class="svg-image" width="150" height="150" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-150-150-10.jpg" />

        <defs>
            <clipPath id="clip-triangle">
                <polygon points="0,0 75,75 150,150 0,150" />
            </clipPath>
        </defs>

        <defs>
            <clipPath id="clip-square">
                <polygon points="0,0 0,150 150, 150 150, 0" />
            </clipPath>
        </defs>
    </a>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
.svg-image, .svg-link {
    clip-path: url(#clip-triangle);
}

.svg-image:hover, .svg-link:hover {
    clip-path: url(#clip-square);
}

.svg-image,
.svg-link {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.2s;
}

#img-1 {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

I want the triangle to grow into a square on the hover state, and then shrink back into a triangle when the cursor leaves the element.

I have tried many different techniques to achieve this but at this point I am at a loss. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look halfway down the page (star to square transition), I think this is what you want http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/animating-css-shapes/

Comment: Thanks, I saw that but the technique covered has very limited browser support at this time. I was hoping to find a different way to do it if possible. If not, it's a good fallback to pursue.

Comment: JS is certainly an option as long as it's supported across all current major browsers and mobile devices. (The above-linked technique does not work in FireFox.)

Comment: For js look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186441/shape-tween-in-javascript

Comment: There is also this: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/01/07/shape-hover-effect-with-svg/

Comment: I found another link that will probably help you: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3081153http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3081153

Answer (score 2):

This shows you how to begin a SMIL solution which will work in Chrome and Firefox and possibly IE if you use [fakesmile](http://leunen.me/fakesmile/). You could do the easing using [calcMode="spline"](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#ValueAttributes) which I haven't done here.

Note that in order to keep the - in the id I have to escape it with a \ sign in the begin attribute.

```css
.svg-image, .svg-link {
    clip-path: url(#clip-triangle);
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg-1" class="clip-svg" width="150" height="150">
    <a xlink:href="http://google.com" class="svg-link">
        <image id="img-1" class="svg-image" width="150" height="150" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/mediawiki/a/a9/Example.jpg" />
     
        <defs>
            <clipPath id="clip-triangle">
                <polygon points="0,0 75,75 150,150 150,0">
                    <animate begin="img\-1.mouseover" attributeName="points" to="0,0 0,150 150,150 150, 0" dur="0.5s" fill="freeze"/>
                    <animate begin="img\-1.mouseout" attributeName="points" to="0,0 75,75 150,150 150,0" dur="0.5s" fill="freeze"/>
                </polygon>
            </clipPath>
        </defs>
    </a>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks that's an interesting solution! Problem for me is that it does not want to work in Safari even after attempting to load in fakesmile. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I'll keep plugging away at it.

Answer (score 1):

Using [this](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/animating-css-shapes/) link I was able to create the effect you are looking for with the following code, this is an option for your effect. As you've mentioned, browser compatibility isn't great for this, however it does work on Chrome Version 36.0.1985.125 m

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="svg-link">
    <img id="img-1" src="http://wpdemo.rohitink.com/sixteen/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/image-alignment-150x150.jpg"/>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
#img-1{
    shape-inside:polygon(0 0, 75px 75px, 150px 150px, 0 150px);
    transition:all 2s ease;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 75px 75px, 150px 150px, 0 150px);
}
#img-1:hover{
    shape-inside:polygon(0 0, 150px 0, 150px 150px, 0 150px);
    -webkit-clip-path:polygon(0 0, 150px 0, 150px 150px, 0 150px);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/mLnhbkL3/)

Comment: Thanks this looks great! Works in Chrome and Safari, but not in FireFox and IE. I would like to get the effect working across the latest releases of these 4 major browsers via some alternate method, but if it just isn't possible I will accept this answer.

Comment: One other minor issue I found with this approach is that the initial hover state for the link is a square, meaning that if a user hovers outside the bounds of the triangle but within the bounds of the square it would trigger the animation.