# Animate Clip-path with URL FireFox

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

I'm playing around with `SVG` and `clip-path`, but since `SMIL` is deprecated, I have to resort to using CSS to draw and animate my shapes.

My goal is to have some triangles on top of each other, which fold out at the point on the right or left of the triangle, depending of which way it points.

I figured it out in Chrome by doing the following:

```
.elementRight {
  margin-top: -140px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 20%, 100% 50%, 100% 50%, 0% 80%);
  transition: all .2s;
  position: relative;
}

.elementRight:hover {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 20%, 100% 20% ,100% 80%, 0% 80%);
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Adding a few more lines of CSS and a few more elements, the result is the following:
[image]
It's not very smooth in the GIF, but the [Fiddle can be found here](https://jsfiddle.net/gLpgoopr/6/).

When I try to achieve the same in Firefox, I have to resort to `clip-path: url(#name);`. I can add a css `:hover`, so it changes what clip-path is chosen from the HTML, but it won't transition smoothly:
[image]
This version can be found (and experienced only in Firefox!) in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gLpgoopr/7/).

Does anyone have an idea how to transition this smoothly from a triangle to a square in Firefox? The basic experience for the user is the same (on hover, it becomes square), but I like the smoothness that Chrome, Opera and Safari deliver.

Comment: I haven't checked the specs but I don't think they can be transitioned when using `url()` syntax.

Comment: I experienced the same, which is why I came here to see if there's another possibility :)

Comment: Animate the points and leave the url alone, something like I did here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368967/how-do-i-animate-this-svg-clip-path-hover-effect/25372255#25372255

Comment: @RobertLongson That seems to work. Only partially though, since I have to use an ID. Is there any way to use classes and only let the currently-hovered SVG to animate?

Comment: SMIL works on IDs, not classes. You'd need to provide a clip-path per shape and then just animate that clip-path on hover.

Comment: The good news is that Firefox now supports `clip-path` with basic shapes (like `polygon`) without a prefix for about a year now and it's animatable. The bad news is that it needs the `layout.css.clip-path-shapes.enabled` flag set to `true` in `about:config` to work.